# where the installer files located on galaxy tab those are downloaded from Android marketplace

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

I have downloaded several free applicaitons from android marketplace. Now, I want to transfer these application to another galaxy tab. But, however, I can't find any installers(.apk files) for those application on my tab. How will I locate them and transfer the applications please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download any app. for creating backups of the installed applications. Astro File Manager is one such reliable application available in Android Market.

[image]

The apk files could be then send via. bluetooth, email,...

[Download Astro File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result)